# BreezeJs DataModal using EF as a design tool

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am using resource at [EF as Design tool](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/ef-design-tool) resource in my project. I have three different project in my solution.

DTO - Has DbContext and DTO object and method to return metadata as describe in the example.

Service - Has WebApi method and called getmetaData from DTO project and return string as -

```
[BreezeController]
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string MetaData()
    {          
        return new LifeAudit_DTO.DtoMetaData().MetaData();
    }
}
```

3. Third project as WebApi project(Using vs2013) has routing information and refernce service library and this is my main interface(UI) project.

1. I am using EF6 and latest Breeze from Nuget Project.
2. I am setting Database init as null, following is my Datacontext code -

   ```
   internal class LifeAuditDbContext : DbContext
   {
    static LifeAuditDbContext()
    {
       Database.SetInitializer<LifeAuditDbContext>(null);
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonDtoConfiguration());            
     }
   public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. On calling service I got following error -

   {
   $id: "1",
   $type: "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
   Message: "An error has occurred.",
   ExceptionMessage: "An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.",
   ExceptionType: "System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException",
   StackTrace: " at System.Web.Http.ApiController.d_*1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()",
   InnerException: {
   $id: "2",
   $type: "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
   Message: "An error has occurred.",
   ExceptionMessage: "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.",
   ExceptionType: "System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException",
   StackTrace: " at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)",
   InnerException: {
   $id: "3",
   $type: "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
   Message: "An error has occurred.",
   ExceptionMessage: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)",
   ExceptionType: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
   StackTrace: " at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c*_DisplayClass2f.b_*2d() at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b__0() at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)"
   }
   }
   }

It looks like it try to use connection for EF, but I am passing null.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Daljit

Comment: Looks like you're not using the context for metadata _only_.

Comment: Thanks I will try this weekend and let you know. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You showed us your *real* `DbContext`. You didn't show us the *phony* `DbContext` that exists only for DTO metadata generation.

I was expecting something like

```
// notice the "Dto" in the class name
internal class LifeAuditDbDtoContext : DbContext {

    // class constructor
    static LifeAuditDbDtoContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<LifeAuditDbDtoContext>(null);
    }

    // instance constructor
    public LifeAuditDbDtoContext() : base("Dummy") {
    /// stuff
    }
}
```

**This Dto version is the `DbContext` that needs the null initializer for sure!**

#### Still not working?

Sometimes I think I have to give EF a phony connection string even if the initializer is null.

> I'm not sure why and this could be voodoo.

Try this and let us know if it works for you (note the name of string and the db is "dummy". The dummy database should not exist nor be created):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Dummy" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dummy.mdf;Initial Catalog=dummy;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    ... other real strings ...
```

Of course you could supply the real connection string name instead and dispense with the phony. The null initializer ensures that the app will not re-initialize the database. But personally, if EF is looking for a database connection string for this dummy `DbContext`, I don't want it to go anywhere near my real database.

Comment: Thanks I will try this weekend and let you know. Thanks for reply. Do i need to create Phony DBContext as well like fakeDbContext and use that to create metadata. Thanks for quick reply. Breeze is great and thanks ideablade for it.

Comment: Yes, the Phony DB Context is the key to using EF to generate metadata for your DTOs. It surfaces the entity types and relationships that the client should see as the client interacts with the API. But, being a fake, it is **never, ever used for anything other than generating the metadata**. Real queries use the real DbContext and you then project the data returned the real model query results into the DTO classes. Everything happens in a repository class, not the Web API controller. The [EF as a Design Tool](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/ef-design-tool) topic explains in detail.

Comment: Sorry is not my dbcontext is fake or phony, because it does not point towards any database. Sorry if it is very dump question, how I can create phony dbcontext as I do not want to use EF as database-object mapper. thanks for help

Comment: thanks, passing dummy connectionstring works for me, thanks a lot.